# Lead detail page is not showing on Partner Portal after record is submitted for Approval

Tags: partner-communities

[image]I have configured Approval process for Lead object, If partner user is created new lead on Partner portal then automation process is submitted lead record to approval. However, i can't able to see the lead record detail page after record is created and getting below error message.

Looks like there's a problem.

This record is locked. If you need to edit it, contact your admin.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Does the detail page have any input field / component that aims to edit the record? Otherwise, I don't see why you would get that error just in VIEW mode. If there is any lightning component using forceRecordData in EDIT mode maybe that is the cause.

Comment: Hi Gien De Marcos, no i didn't use any lighting component to edit the lead record but i can see the opportunity detail page when i submit it for approval but not lead detail page.

Comment: Thanks for adding the detail! Please include a pic of the lightning builder so we see the 2 components that are causing the problem

Comment: Hi Gien De Marcos, I didn't used any lighting component to edit the lead record but i can see the detail page when i logged into the portal with Salesforce license user but it's not working with partner portal license.

Comment: What throws me off is that your detail page seems like it has a Dashboard embedded. That is not out-of-the-box so someone has likely configured the Detail page to look that way. My best guess with the information provided is that the Lightning Detail page has a component that is forcing a Lead update and maybe some create automation process is editing the record, that is why is locked. The other thing I would look for is a Visualforce page embedded in the page layout that might be forcing an edit on every read? Not sure if it would execute in lightning but worth checking out...

Comment: To review the lightning Detail page go to Setup --> All Communities --> Builder (next to the partner community) --> Then on the top drop-down select the Detail page

Comment: i can see the lead record detail page after i submit the record manually but it's not working when i submit the record via Process builder